# What is the replacement text value that is used to insert a BOOL value, Obj-C, Cocoa-Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I know this is quite sad, but when I have an `NSString` and I want it to have an `int` value, I use the `%d`string value inside of it. What do I use for `BOOL`. I tried `%b`, but that did nothing. What is it?

Comment: BOOL is nothing but an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use %d, a BOOL is an integer.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I forgot that. Thanks, that is what I needed. :)

Comment: BOOL is a 'signed char' not an integer, check objc.h

Comment: The sad part here, is I actually know that. I don't know what happened to me, I completely blanked that out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like these correspond to [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifiers, which lack the capability to print a boolean.

You could use `%d` to use it like an integer (which it is) or print one of two strings upon it being true: `%s` as the format specifier and the parameter being `(b) ? "true" : "false"` where `b` is your `BOOL` variable.

Note: This is from a C programmer's point of view; You might have to write those string constants slightly differently. If the `%s` specifier here expects an `NSString`, you should probably use `@"true"` and `@"false"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more readable you could always define a macro to give you readable output

```
#define STRING_FROM_BOOL(b) (b ? @"YES" : @"NO")

NSLog(@"%@", STRING_FROM_BOOL(NO)); //=> NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Are thinking something like:

```
NSString* num = @"1";
BOOL b = [num intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no specifier for booleans [print_f ref here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)